# Posting Specific Questions about AGI's STK

Tags: discussion

> Should questions about the usage and characteristics of STK be posted on SpaceExploration SE? Should they be posted in other SE site? Are there guidelines to such questions?

Explaining the point:

AGI's STK is a very well known and widely used software for orbit propagation and other mission analysis related tasks.

Unlike Matlab and many other software tools, STK has very poor reference documentation.

As an example, if I check Matlab's documentation for "ECEF" I find for instance [the reference for the lla2ecef block](https://www.mathworks.com/help/aeroblks/llatoecefposition.html?searchHighlight=ecef&s_tid=doc_srchtitle) , which in turn offers a link to [a page explaining coordinate systems](https://www.mathworks.com/help/aeroblks/about-aerospace-coordinate-systems.html). Both provide reference in the literature as well.

If I check AGI's documentation for "ECEF" I find two pages mentioning it and no explanation on what it is. Luckily for me, I know what ECEF is conceptually.

However, If I'm building a scenario and I believe I should work with times in UTC, I only have the option for UTCG. I don't know what UTCG is, nor if and when it is equivalent to UTC. Checking the documentation for "UTCG" nothing helpful pops up. There is menu somewhere expanding this as "Gregorian UTC" (much better but not quite there).

Point is, in general, STK documentation forces you to do a lot of research, it would be nice to post questions here and over time be able to find the answers in this (or other SE site) in past questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems perfectly reasonable to me to ask STK questions here.

Comment: I agree, seems in line with our decision on Python: https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/995/58.

Comment: It would need a tag then, but that will happen automagically when enough questions.